# How to correct date in EST format?

Tags: java, date

In my struts based web application, I am getting data regarding next run of scheduler. I then passed this to a method which will set the invoice date. What exactly happening is, we need to manage the transaction for an entire month. After completion of the month, the corresponding invoice will be generating on 1st date of subsequent month. For example, if all the transactions occur in January 2020, then the invoice date should be 1st February 2020.

But the existing method seems to be buggy. It displays the end user the date

*We will invoice this on the 01 July 2022 12:00 AM EST*

It should be

*We will invoice this on the 01 February 2020 12:00 AM EST*

**SNIPPET:**

```
List<ScheduleTaskInfo> sInfo = sManagement
                        .getSchedulerTaskList(SchedulerTask.BillingViewTask,
                                cProduct.getAccountId(), cProduct.getId(),
                                cProduct.getRunningId());

if (sInfo != null && sInfo.size() > 0) {
                    ScheduleTaskInfo info = sInfo.get(0);
                    try {
                        setInvoiceDate(dateUtil.getFormattedTime(
                                info.getNextRun(), "MM-dd-yyyy H:mm"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    }

                }
```

**UTILITY METHOD**

```
public  String getFormattedTime(String dateString, String format)
            throws ParseException {
        String result = null;
        try {
            format = getDateFormat(format);
            result = getESTTime(getStringToUtilDate(dateString, format));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return result;

    }
```

**getStringToUtilDate**

```
public  java.util.Date getStringToUtilDate(String dateString,
            String format) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sd = null;
        try {
            format = getDateFormat(format);
             sd = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return sd.parse(dateString);
    }
```

**CODE RESPONSIBLE FOR GENERATING EST FORMAT IS BELOW**

*The below snippet returns the date as 01 July 2022 12:00 AM EST*

```
public  String getESTTime(java.util.Date date) {
    String strDate = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd  MMMM yyyy h:mm aa zzz");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  strDate;
}
```

How do I rectify the same?

Comment: works fine for me using `new Date ()` outputs as `08  January 2020 2:36 AM EST`

Comment: the info object is populated via data fetching from db

Comment: There seem to be many steps which we do not have the code for e.g.  `format = getDateFormat(format);` (looks strange as well) and `getStringToUtilDate`

Comment: Don't use EST, use (e.g.) America/New_York. [Explanation](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ThreeLetterTimeZoneID). And [be careful with the spelling](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/InvalidTimeZoneID).

Comment: Your code is a mess.  First your start with `format = getDateFormat(format);
            result = getESTTime(getStringToUtilDate(dateString, format));` and then `getStringToUtilDate` which does `getDateFormat` and parsing and then you do `getESTTime`  which ignores the format but then does almost exactly the same stuff

Comment: I need to clean the same Scary, please suggest me the best solution for the same,its an exisitng implementation

Answer (score 0):

Would prefer using Java 8 LocalDateTime api instead of old Java util dates.It is much cleaner.

```
LocalDateTime nextRunDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-01-01 00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));

/*Custom Date Manipulation Logic*/
LocalDateTime expectedInvoiceDate=nextRunDate.plusMonths(1);

String invoiceDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a z")
        .format(
                expectedInvoiceDate.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
        );

System.out.println(invoiceDate);
```

Choose the time Zone as per your need.

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/convert-date-time-to-est-est5edt/